# Providers of fake DOIs?

Tags: publications, journals, doi, cross-referencing

How to find and check providers of fake Digital Object Identifier (DOI) numbers? What are the consequences of using fake DOI numbers? How can I know is DOI number actually fake?

Comment: Not sure, but can't you check where a DOI points to on https://www.doi.org/ ?

Comment: Seem to remember putting a comment asking what was meant by DOI - would have appreciated a notification of the edit instead of someone just deleting my comment. But that seems to be how some act. Sad.

Comment: @SolarMike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130975/are-comments-ephemeral-and-what-should-be-done-with-informative-comments Also, I think it's quite reasonable to assume people know what a DOI is.  We have a tag for it and I use DOIs several times a day.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist sure: Drunk Or Incapable...

Comment: @SolarMike: What a shame!

Comment: It's a side-note, but DOIs commonly contain letters, so calling them numbers seems at best unnecessary. The I=Identifier provides a more suitable noun anyway.

Answer (score 2):

DOIs are registered and managed by [Registration Agencies](https://www.doi.org/registration_agencies.html) appointed by the International DOI Foundation. All registered DOI numbers resolve through https://doi.org/ - if it doesn't resolve it's not a DOI. A DOI can be applied to many different things so the fact that content has a DOI doesn't say anything about the quality or validity of the content. There's a blog post about this - https://www.crossref.org/blog/dois-unambiguously-and-persistently-identify-published-trustworthy-citable-online-scholarly-literature-right/

Comment: "All registered DOI numbers resolve through https://doi.org/ - if it doesn't resolve it's not a DOI." In my experience this is not true.  I have obtained a DOI from a journal a few days before it began to resolve.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist The journal did not give you a DOI.  It gave you a magic cookie that transformed into a DOI when doi.org started to resolve it.

Comment: @JeffE It was exactly the same text as the DOI.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist And yet its meaning changed when it was blessed by doi.org.

Comment: A DOI functions when it's registered so if you get a DOI prior to it being registered it's a DOI that isn't active yet - there's nothing magic or blessed about it. I could give you a URL to a domain name that isn't registered yet and the link wouldn't work until the domain name is registered. However, I could also just make a random string of numbers and letters that look like a domain name or a DOI - e.g. 10.65421/1238djkad - is it a DOI?

Answer (score 0):

The EU-backed [FREYA](https://www.project-freya.eu/en) is currently working on a project called 'common DOI search' to address this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Attempt to resolve the DOI digitally. If the number doesn’t resolve then it doesn’t currently identify a digital object adequately.

Do you mean “how do I identify DOIs resolving to objects that are academic garbage, lack peer review or a publisher exhibiting academic standards of review prior to publication?”